# How to use django-jalali calendar in tempates?

Tags: django, templates

Im new to Django and im trying to use django in a Persian app, therefore I need users pick i a date(jalali date) and send it to server.
I've used django-jalali in admin area and its working fine, but I need to use this in front-end too.
I've set locale to Asia/Tehran and Time Zone to fa but default date picker shows up Gregorian calendar. please help me with that. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

There is a super simple way for this:
1-you should first have a date picker in your front. Here is a jalali date picker you can use:
https://github.com/majidh1/JalaliDatePicker
I've also put this implemented HTML code using the date picker:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Date picker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@majidh1/jalalidatepicker/dist/jalalidatepicker.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://unpkg.com/@majidh1/jalalidatepicker/dist/jalalidatepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" data-jdp name="date" autocomplete="off">

    <button type="submit">ذخیره</button>
</form>

<script>
    jalaliDatepicker.startWatch();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2-now you can send a request containing the jalali date from your HTML code to your Django project and convert it to Georgian date for your optional use

```
from itertools import groupby

from django.shortcuts import render

from jdatetime import datetime, date


def jalali_to_gregorian(jalali_date):
    jalali_datetime = datetime.strptime(jalali_date, "%Y/%m/%d").date()
    gregorian_datetime = jalali_datetime.togregorian()
    return gregorian_datetime


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("it is post")

        date_value = request.POST.get('date')

        gregorian_date = jalali_to_gregorian(date_value)

        print(gregorian_date) #you can do whatever you want instead of printing

        return render('your render')

    return render('your render')
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a package called `django-jalali-date` which provide you good tools to work with jalali dates. Here is an example of how you can add jalali_date input with datepicker from it's [doc](https://github.com/a-roomana/django-jalali-date)

```
from django import forms
from jalali_date.fields import JalaliDateField, SplitJalaliDateTimeField
from jalali_date.widgets import AdminJalaliDateWidget, 
AdminSplitJalaliDateTime


class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('name', 'date', 'date_time')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'] = JalaliDateField(label=_('date'), # date format is  "yyyy-mm-dd"
            widget=AdminJalaliDateWidget # optional, to use default datepicker
        )

        # you can added a "class" to this field for use your datepicker!
        # self.fields['date'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'jalali_date-date'})

        self.fields['date_time'] = SplitJalaliDateTimeField(label=_('date time'), 
            widget=AdminSplitJalaliDateTime # required, for decompress DatetimeField to JalaliDateField and JalaliTimeField
        )
```